# How to hand over an HTTP-Response returned by a REST-API with Spring Boot?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I'm implementing a REST-API using the Spring Boot framework. Now this REST-API has to call another REST-API and just needs to pass through the incoming HTTP-Response as is, basically functioning as a gateway.

Is there a simple way to achieve this without mapping the response to a bean?

Comment: What is your http verb I.e. do you get the json request body? How is the request look like?

Comment: The response originally is created by the CrudRepository of Spring Boot. So it even supports the HATEOAS criteria, which might be a problem since the gateway should not allow certain operations on certain ressources, but since the CrudRepository is used the response indicates more operations that should actually be supported. I just wanted to start with the GET verb but eventually all the common verbs should be supported. So the question could be expanded by how I can pass through HTTP requests as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use RestTemplate. Its only a few lines of code.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

This would map in into a String if that if fine for you:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 String fooResourceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/foos";
 ResponseEntity<String> respons = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl + "/1", String.class);
```

Comment: So the only way to accomplish what I want is by using beans?